# c# PDFSharp - what's the point of Table.Clone?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am generating a PDF document using PDFSharp which uses the same (small) table over and over.

I saw that it is possible to clone an entire table. I made a master table with all the core settings I would need and a couple of rows, thinking i could simply use the `Table.Clone()` method on the master table to bring be back a nice new table that could be midified and then drawn to the document.

Cloning works, but when it comes to actually draw the table to the page, an `System.ArgumentFormat` exception is thrown:

`"Value of '0' is not valid for 'emSize'. 'emSize' should be greater than 0 and less than or equal to System.Single.MaxValue.\r\nParameter name: emSize"` (in System.Drawing.dll)

It seems every table has to be added to the page using the `page.AddTable()` method.

If that's the case, what is the purpose of Table.Clone() if its impossible to then draw the cloned table to a page?

Here is a greatly simplified test case:

```
Table test_table = new Table();
test_table.Style = "Table";
test_table.Borders.Color = Colors.Black;
test_table.AddColumn(50);
test_table.AddColumn(50);

Row table_row_1 = test_table.AddRow();
table_row_1.Format.Font.Name = "Verdana";
table_row_1.Format.Font.Size = 8;

Row table_row_2 = test_table.AddRow();
table_row_2.Format.Font.Name = "Verdana";
table_row_2.Format.Font.Size = 8;

Table cloned_table = test_table.Clone();
cloned_table.Rows[0].Cells[0].AddParagraph("row 1 cell 1");
cloned_table.Rows[0].Cells[1].AddParagraph("row 1 cell 2");
cloned_table.Rows[1].Cells[0].AddParagraph("row 2 cell 1");
cloned_table.Rows[1].Cells[1].AddParagraph("row 2 cell 2");

test_table.SetEdge(0, 0, cloned_table.Columns.Count, cloned_table.Rows.Count, Edge.Box, BorderStyle.Single, 0.75, Colors.Black);
MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer cloned_table_renderer = new DocumentRenderer(doc);
cloned_table_renderer.PrepareDocument();
cloned_table_renderer.RenderObject(gfx, 50, 50, 100, cloned_table);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table that was added to a section has a parent. When you try to add the table again, you will get an exception.

Using `Clone()` you get a copy of the table that has no parent and can be added to the section using `Add(tableClone)`.

You do not use `Add()`, instead you use `RenderObject()`. I don't know why your code isn't working.

Typically you add the table to a section and have MigraDoc create the document for you - this way the table will automatically break across multiple pages when needed.

Exception problem not yet solved, but purpose of Clone is explained.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give the section.Add() method a try and see if that will work.

Comment: Using page.Add(cloned_table) worked. I could then use RenderObject to draw the table to the page.

Comment: Oh and the reason I use RenderObject() is because the position of the table is very specific.