# PdfSharp Cloning a page: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I am reading in a PDF and trying to duplicate some pages in a PDF that I am creating.  However when I try to save the created PDF, an exception is thrown with the infamous

> An item with the same key has already been added

I found the same error mentioned in [Pdf Document Save to stream method throwing exception](http://forum.pdfsharp.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1406&start=0#p4173) (PdfSharp forum from 2010), but no resolution was mentioned.  and the SO [c# PDFSharp - what's the point of Table.Clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27170832/31326) appears to be the same sort of problem (but I do not see how to apply it to my case)

My test code is:
(Note using latest PdfSharp via Nuget)

```
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;

namespace TestError
{
    public class TestCode
    {
        public void DupePages(string inFilePath, string outFilePath)
        {
            var inDoc = PdfReader.Open(inFilePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
            var outDoc = new PdfDocument();

            outDoc.AddPage((PdfPage)inDoc.Pages[0].Clone());
            outDoc.AddPage((PdfPage)inDoc.Pages[0].Clone());

            outDoc.Save(outFilePath); // Exception thrown here
        }
    }
}
```

And the stack trace is

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=An item with the same key has already been added.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfReferenceTable.Compact()
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.PrepareForSave()
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.DoSave(PdfWriter writer)
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.Save(Stream stream, Boolean closeStream)
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.Save(String path)
   at TestError.TestCode.DupePages(String inFilePath, String outFilePath)
```

I have checked that the clone operation is returning different objects, but somehow that is not enough for PdfSharp.

How do I successfully clone a page?

Comment: Does it crash with any PDF file? Having an MCVE would be good. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You can use this template: http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/IssueSubmissions.ashx

Comment: `Table.Clone()` is MigraDoc and not related to PDFsharp's `Page.Clone()`.

Comment: @User241.007 Yes it crashes on any PDF file.  And that code *is* an MCVE

Comment: An MCVE with a VS project and solution would be _more_ complete. I assume you mean "latest PDFsharp" (1.50) and not "latest stable PDFsharp" (1.32). Different matter: I don't understand what you try to achieve. Maybe there are more efficient options that do not use `Clone()` and that work without exception.

Comment: @User241.007 I was testing with "Latest stable 1.32" (I prefer not to use beta software from Nuget) and that was causing the exception.  I swapped that out for the latest 1.5 Beta and now it fails in a different way - it creates the PDF but the second page is blank and Adobe reader thinks that it has a problem.  I'll have to update my question.  As for what I want - I am trying to make independent, duplicate copies of pages that originate in a PDF read from a file - as per my code.

Comment: @User241.007 Actually it now works as I expected with the Beta version (after a minor code tweak).  I'm going to end up answering my own question

Answer (score 2):

My original code was tested with PdfSharp `Latest stable 1.32.3057`.  When using this version if I didn't use the `Clone` then the `AddPage` would only add a reference to the page and not duplicate it.

However when prompted by User241.007 to go to the `Latest prerelease 1.5.4619-beta4c` version, things changed.  The exception was no longer thrown, but the resulting file was not correct.  In a moment of clarity I changed the code slightly to the following and now it works as expected.

```
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;

namespace TestError
{
    public class TestCode
    {
        public void DupePages(string inFilePath, string outFilePath)
        {
            var inDoc = PdfReader.Open(inFilePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
            var outDoc = new PdfDocument();

            var page = inDoc.Pages[0];
            outDoc.AddPage(page);
            page.Rotate = 0;
            outDoc.AddPage(page);

            outDoc.Save(outFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

The setting of `Rotate` proves conclusively in my case that an independent duplicate of the page has been added to the `outDoc`.  As when I view the result the two pages have different rotations (The source PDF I am testing with actually has the pages with an initial rotation of 90)

Normally I have Nuget set to not show me prerelease versions, but in this case it might be the option I want.